# Accessing original int comparison from int-derived class with overloaded comparison operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

I have an int-derived class with overloaded comparison operator.

In the body of the overloaded methods I need to use the original operator.

The toy example:

```
>>> class Derived(int):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return super(Derived, self).__eq__(other)
```

works fine with Python 3.3+, but fails with Python 2.7 with exception `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__eq__'`.

I can think about several walkarrounds, which I found not very clean:

```
return int(self) == other
```

requires creation of a new `int` object just to compare it, while

```
try:
    return super(Derived, self).__eq__(other)
except AttributeError:
    return super(Derived, self).__cmp__(other) == 0
```

splits the control flow based on the Python version, which I find terribly messy (so is inspecting the Python version explicitly).

How can I access the original integer comparison in an elegant way working with Python 2.7 and 3.3+?

Comment: You can access the `int` comparing method via `super.__eq__` . However, depending on the python version built-in types comparing methods are implemented much different. Therefore python2 `super.eq` requires 1 argument (other) whereas python3 requires 2 (self and other)

Comment: Do you consider `int(self) == int(other)` too messy?

Comment: @Phillip it creates one more object than `int(self) == other`

Comment: @abukaj Ah, you had already thought about that. Sorry. I don't think that the overhead you're assuming is real. It would be insane for any Python implementation not to optimize the built-in integer type, e.g., *really* instanciate a full fledged object each time you have an integer somewhere. (That is, I would do some benchmarking before continuing to worry about this optimization.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should define the `__eq__` in the `int` before defining the class. For example:

```
int = 5
def int.__eq__(self, other):
    return self.real == other
IntDerived = Derived(int)
```

This should give the `super` class an `__eq__` attribute.

---

EDITED

---

The main idea worked, but it has been brought to my attention that the code isn't working. So: improved code:

```
class Derived(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.real == other

Int = 5
D = Derived(Int)
D.__eq__(4) #Output: False
D.__eq__(5) #Output: True
```

Comment: That's not python.

Comment: @GreenHawk1220 I will accept the answer if you put the `__eq__()` method in the `Derived` class definition (and make it work in Python). The idea of accessing the `.real` attribute works, but the code is not Python.

Comment: Glad I helped. God bless.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 and 3 are significantly different from each other so I think you should bite the bullet and check versions. That is only to be expected if you're trying to write code that works on both (sooner or later in my experience you find something you have to patch). To avoid any performance impact you could do something like:

```
from six import PY2

class Derived(int):
    if PY2:
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return super(Derived, self).__cmp__(other) == 0
    else:
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return super(Derived, self).__eq__(other)
```

That's what I'd do. If I really wanted to subclass `int`...

If you really don't want to, perhaps you could try:

```
class Derived(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self ^ other) == 0
```

Obviously if you care about performance you'll have to do some profiling with the rest of your code and find out if either of them is significantly worse...

Comment: I like the latter approach, however it does not work when `other` is a float

Answer (score 1):

Both versions implement an `__xor__` method, you could try this:

```
class Derived(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return not super(Derived, self).__xor__(other)
```

Comment: I like the answer. Not very clean nor works with comparison to float, though. Also, I think there is no necessity to create `super` object, `self` is enough. `self ^ other` may be even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

using `hasattr` avoids creating a new `int` object, catching an exception or explicitly checking for the Python version.

The below code works on both Python 2.7 and 3.3+:

```
class Derived(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return super(Derived, self).__cmp__(other) == 0 if hasattr(Derived, "__cmp__") else super(Derived, self).__eq__(other)
```